# datatables in javascript get row column attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to get the "data-" attribute in the `<td>` elements of a jquery datatable plugin:

i can recovery all the rows of the datatable with:

```
$("#tabla-transmisiones").dataTable()._('tr', {"filter": "applied"})
```

or

```
table.rows().data()
```

but **I need to read the "data-" attributes of each `<td>` element in datatable row.**

Comment: please elaborate your question. what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution:

```
$("#tablename").dataTable()._('tr', {"filter": "applied"}).rows(nrow).nodes().to$().find('td[data-yourattr]').data("yourattr");
```